# Formula to split up statement between cells?

Tags: excel

In Excell, if I am writing, and what I am writing goes out of bounds, is there anyway to automatically shift that to the next cell? So for instance, if I was writing "My Name is Ian" in C1, but "is Ian" went out of bounds, it would automatically be shifted to C2?

Answer (score 0):

The easier thing to do is to resize the cell to fit your text or insert line breaks with shift-enter

If you double-click on the boundary between two rows/columns at the left/top of the page, it will auto-resize that row/column to fit the contents.

Comment: I can't do that because I have very limited space on the form, and cannot change the entire row. Thank you for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't align your text on the left** (make sure no any alignment button is pressed while you are on the cell), the text should be shown over the other cells as long as they are empty. Isn't it a good solution for your request?